# not able to figure out what sender to return from a leadingSwipeActions for a prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, prepareforreuse

Sorry, I am brand new swift and IOS development but I have a table view with each element in the table view I can tap on the item to go to my edit screen which determines the information in the table cell. I would like to also have a `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` bring up an edit button that uses the same segue way to get to into edit screen as taping the cell. The issue is that my `prepare(for segue:)` statement for the handling of the tap segue keeps failing because of the sender of leadingSwipeAction. Now I am really confused about what I should put as my sender in my leadingSwipeAction. I have tried a `UITableViewCell()` which failed this guard statement:

`guard let ViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController else {
                             fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }`

for being a UIView() and then I tried sending a `taskCellTableViewCell` which is the object/class I called an individual cell but that returned a nil/empty cell which failed another guard statement in the prepare. So now I am confused about how to get and send the actual cell that leadingSwipeAction was performed on. I hope anyone can help me figure out the correct sender I need to return to pass the prepare. Thanks

Here is the code used for the leadingSwipeAction and prepare:

```
//leading swipe for editing code
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (contextualAction, view, actionPerformed: (Bool) -> ()) in
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: UITableViewCell())
        actionPerformed(true)

    }

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [edit])
}

    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)

    switch(segue.identifier ?? "") {

        case "addItem":
        os_log("Adding a new task.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)

        case "showDetail":
        guard let ViewController = segue.destination as? ViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
        }

        guard let selectedTaskCell = sender as? taskCellTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender)")
        }

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedTaskCell) else {
            fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
        }

        let selectedTask = tasks[indexPath.row]
        ViewController.Task = selectedTask

        default:
        fatalError("Unexpected Segue Identifier; \(segue.identifier)")

    }
}
```

it fails trying to use the showDetail segue again.

Also here is a pastebin of the complete code of the project [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/8Jh88BBZ)

Comment: When you say it fails, is there any error text associated with the failure?

Comment: for when I used the sender of `UITableViewCell()` the error text is `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpected sender: Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x7faf13439810; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0x600003a49ba0>>)`

Comment: for when I used I used my cell class as the sender its error is `Thread 1: Fatal error: The selected cell is not being displayed by the table` coming from 

`guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedTaskCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a `tableViewCell` can be used as a sender, are you not able to set this to the `ViewController` you are initiating the segue from, that should work.

Comment: I tried to send a TableViewController but that did not work either. Does it have to be done in the viewController? I thought since it's an action on my table view sending data over to the viewController aka detail screen that it would have to be done in the TableViewController? Also, I am pretty sure I just do not know how to put the sender  because I have to put to get an actual cell that the leadSwipeAction was performed on to fix it but I could be wrong

Comment: Generally I just use self as the sender, I'm not sure the sender property actually does anything anyway. This is the description for it from apple

The object that you want to use to initiate the segue. This object is made available for informational purposes during the actual segue.

Comment: I tired self and index.row as the sender but that still did not return the cell and pass the guard statements. is there a way to get the cell from self with indexPath.row?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after searching around and changing my google search using every buzz word I can think of I finally found the answer. To make the sender be the current cell that the `LeadingSwipeAction` is performed on the sender needs to set to `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` which takes the tableView being passed into the LeadingSwipe func and gets cell form the indexPath.